# Passing data from one view controller to other view controller through xib file

Tags: iphone, xib, viewcontroller

I want to make one app and it include form submition . In this i create one new project by single view application. In this firstViewController I have put button and by pressing it , it redirect to secondViewController.

In this i have a form. and want to take data from user and by submit button i want to redirect this to thirdViewController and want to print the form data on thirdViewController.

In firstViewController.m file i have written

```
-(IBAction)nextVCButton:(id)sender
{

SecondViewController *tempView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

NSLog(@"name : %@",self.nameTextField.text);
tempView.fullName = self.nameTextField.text;
[tempView setFullName:self.fullName];
[self.view addSubview:tempView.view];
```

}

In SecondViewController.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

NSLog(@"received info %@", [self.fullName description]);

self.nameLabel.text = [self.fullName description];

}
```

In log i am getting (name :)  value but in secondViewController received info is null.

I am doing this all by using xib file. No use of Storyboard.

Please help me to get this form data to secondViewController.

Thanks.

Comment: using addsubview to load second view controller?seriously?Then why `UINavigationController` class being made?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Comment: which way is more preferable for navigate one view to another by button and again from that controller navigate to third controller through button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry , I couldn't get why you have done these two line code :

```
tempView.fullName = self.nameTextField.text;
[tempView setFullName:self.fullName];
```

Instead ,
Make a property of `NSString` in Second View Controller's `.h file`

```
@property (nonatomic,retain)    NSString *strFullName;
```

and synthesize in `.m file`.

```
@synthesize strFullName;
```

Now ,

```
-(IBAction)nextVCButton:(id)sender
{

SecondViewController *tempView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

NSLog(@"name : %@",self.nameTextField.text);
tempView.strFullName = self.nameTextField.text;
[self.view addSubview:tempView.view];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. I have already done same thing but because of this  line [tempView setFullName:self.fullName]; I am getting null. Now after removing this it is working fine. I spend my 2 days for this. thanks for your valuable answer.

Comment: which way is more preferable for navigate one view to another by button and again from that controller navigate to third controller through button?

Comment: It can be according to the requirement of your application.

Comment: for this same question i am using both times addSubView for navigate to another page. By pressing button in second view controller it is giving error of " Thread 1 : EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x69202020) "

Comment: But if you want to move to second view then you need to use pushViewController , else if you want to add that second view on first view , then you need to add subview on first view.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31907/discussion-between-zeel-and-iuser)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `Navigation controller` if you want to navigate from one view controller to another view controller. well here you need to do property- synthesize the iVar "fullName" in `ThirdViewController`. and retain the value in `SecondViewController` .

**1. ThirdViewController.h**

```
 @property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *fullName;
```

**2. ThirdViewController.m**

```
@synthisize fullName;
dealloc {
[fullName release];
}
```

**3. SecondViewController.m**

```
-(IBAction)nextVCButton:(id)sender
{

SecondViewController *tempView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

NSLog(@"name : %@",self.nameTextField.text);
tempView.fullName = self.nameTextField.text; 
[tempView setFullName:self.fullName];
[self.view addSubview:tempView.view];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try presentViewController method instead of `addSubview`....

```
-(IBAction)nextVCButton:(id)sender
{
    SecondViewController *tempView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

    NSLog(@"name : %@",self.nameTextField.text);
    tempView.strFullName = self.nameTextField.text;
    [self.view addSubview:tempView.view];
    [self presentViewController:tempView animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```